# Unable to call a function from Fixture.before Method

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to implement a fixture with multiple tests where all depend on each other
Therefore I want to clean the Database and perform login only one time from the Fixture.before Method
So it will look like this:

```
fixture `testProject`.page(baseUrl)
    .before(async t => {
    await loginPM.login()
    await base.clearDB()
})
.beforeEach(async t => {
// some steps before each test
})
test 1
test 2 
test 3
```

This scenario throws the following exception:

---

***Error in fixture.before hook - Cannot implicitly resolve the test run in the context of which the test controller action should be executed. Use test function's 't' argument instead***

---

Any ideas why testcafe not support calling functions from a Fixture.before Method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixture.before hook runs between tests and doesn't have access to the tested page. Please refer to the following help topic for details on its use: [Fixture.before Method](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/fixture/before.html). If you need to execute test actions (click, typeText, etc) once per fixture before you start all tests, see this module: [testcafe-once-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-once-hook) module. Here is an example of how to use it: https://github.com/AlexKamaev/testcafe-once-hook-example.